# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. only for login page

Tags: python, html, django

I am creating a To-Do application as my first project in `django`.
Everything works fine when I run on local server but when I deploy it to `heroku`, CSRF token is not working on login page only. The app is deployed [here](https://hemant-to-do.herokuapp.com).

Issue: If we try any random or existing user on the login page, it shows CSRF verification failed **BUT** if we open `/register` endpoint i.e. Register a user on the app, it creates user and logs in to that user correctly at them time. Whole app features like adding a new task, editing a task, deleting a task works fine until I `logout` that user.

When I come back to the login page again, I am not able to login with any user account.

I've tried a lot of different methods like services in `Procfile`, environment variables for `SECRET_KEY`, providing `meta` tag in the main.html for csrf token using `content={{ csrf_token }}` but no luck.

Codes:

**settings.py**

```
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = os.getenv('DEBUG', False)

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '.herokuapp.com',
    '127.0.0.1:8000'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', Commented or not commented, it doesn't matter... issue still persists
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

**views.py** for login and register page

```
class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'app/login.html'
    fields = '__all__'
    redirect_authenticated_user = True

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('tasks')


class RegisterView(FormView):
    template_name = 'app/register.html'
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        if user is not None:
            login(self.request, user)
        return super(RegisterView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('tasks')
        return super(RegisterView, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
```

**main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@200&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />

    <link
      rel="shortcut icon"
      href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HemantSachdeva/JokeApi/main/src/static/assets/favicon.ico"
    />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style/main.css' %}">

    <title>To Do Tasks</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">{% block content %} {% endblock %}</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**login.html**

```
{% extends 'app/main.html' %} {% block content %}

<div class="header-bar">
  <h1>Login</h1>
</div>

<div class="card-body">
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Login" />
  </form>

  <p>Don't have an account? <a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a></p>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

**register.html**

```
{% extends 'app/main.html' %} {% block content %}

<div class="header-bar">
  <h1>Register</h1>
</div>

<div class="card-body">
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <label> {{ form.username.label }} <span style="color: red">*</span> </label>
    {{ form.username }}
    <ul>
      <li>150 characters or fewer.</li>
      <li>Letters, digits and @ - + _ . only.</li>
    </ul>

    <label> {{ form.password1.label }} </label>
    {{ form.password1 }} {{ form.password1.help_text }}

    <label> Confirm Password </label>
    {{ form.password2 }} <br />
    {{ form.password2.help_text }}

    <input
      style="margin-top: 10px"
      class="button"
      type="submit"
      value="Register"
    />
  </form>

  <p>Already have an account? <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></p>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**task.html** (where it is supposed to land after successful login)

```
{% extends 'app/main.html' %} {% block content %}

<div class="header-bar">
  <div>
    <h1>Hello {{ request.user|capfirst }}</h1>
    <h3 style="margin: 0">
      You have <i>{{ count }}</i> incomplete task{{ count|pluralize:"s" }}.
    </h3>
  </div>
  {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
  <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
  {% endif %}
</div>

<div id="search-add-wrapper">
  <form method="GET" style="margin-top: 20px; display: flex">
    <input type="text" name="search" value="{{ search_input }}" />
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Search" />
  </form>

  <a id="add-link" href="{% url 'task_new' %}">&#x2b;</a>
</div>

<div class="task-items-wrapper">
  {% for task in tasks %}

  <div class="task-wrapper">
    {% if task.complete %}

    <div class="task-title">
      <div class="task-complete-icon"></div>
      <i>
        <s> {{ task|capfirst }} </s>
      </i>
    </div>
    <p>
      <a href="{% url 'task_edit' task.id %}"
        ><i class="fa fa-edit" style="margin-right: 10px"></i
      ></a>

      <a class="delete-link" href="{% url 'task_delete' task.id %}">&#215;</a>
    </p>

    {% else %}

    <div class="task-title">
      <div class="task-incomplete-icon"></div>
      {{ task|capfirst }}
    </div>
    <p>
      <a href="{% url 'task_edit' task.id %}"
        ><i class="fa fa-edit" style="margin-right: 10px"></i
      ></a>

      <a class="delete-link" href="{% url 'task_delete' task.id %}">&#215;</a>
    </p>

    {% endif %}
  </div>

  {% empty %}
  <p>No task found.</p>
  {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: The error message "CSRF verification failed. Request aborted." is the general heading of that error. There should be more information in the body of the response. For example, the same message is provided when the referer header is absent from the request. The body can give a good indication to what exactly goes wrong. Can you provide all of the error output in your question? (This is because the CSRF middleware check is quite complex.)

Comment: I just fixed it before reading the comment but yes your approach is right.

I never used `DEBUG=True` in production before posting this question so I just tested it and the issue was my host origin was not trusted to `CSRF` so I just added

`CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://hemant-to-do.herokuapp.com']`
to my settings.py and the issue is solved

Answer (score 18):

I never used `DEBUG=True` before posting this question and the error was clearly visible after using that.

Error:

```
Origin checking failed - https://hemant-to-do.herokuapp.com does not match any trusted origins.
```

Solution:

added following to **settings.py**

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'https://hemant-to-do.herokuapp.com'
]
```